# Carbon frame damage from chain

Tags: carbon

Sustained some damage from a chain coming off, and it's done some rather nasty damage to the paint, frame itself looks OK?
Other bikes I own have a metal plate here to protect the frame, is this not standard?
Feels and sounds solid, is it still OK to ride?
Will Specialized repair this under warranty?

[image: damage]

Comment: i can't be sure, but it looks like just paint damage to me. I'd take it to a shop for inspection. If OK'd by the experts, I'd cover it with helicopter, add a chain catcher to the downtube, and call it good.

Comment: @PaulH Helicopter?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus https://www.amazon.com/slp/helicopter-tape/f9svw3m4gqsu4sk

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, too late to edit the original, but i meant "helicopter tape"

Answer (score 1):

From what can be seen in the picture it looks like the damage to paint only. The top layer has been chipped cleanly off, and there are no carbon fibers exposed from the epoxy visible.

That said, I'd have a bike shop look at it in person.

As far as I know, no manufacturer will replace or repair a frame that has sustained damage from the chain or a crash.

Comment: This strikes me as a design flaw (no plate and not enough room to avoid chain suck) but I would be genuinely surprised if it could be warranted. No harm in trying though.